# How to resolve warnings while running newly created Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a new next.js app using `npx create-next-app ./`
I didn’t touch any code or even open it in an editor.

While running this app using `npm run dev`, I get these really long warnings.

```
$ npm run dev

> test@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 1605 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 593 ms (20 modules)
- wait compiling /page (client and server)...
- warn ./node_modules/next/dist/client/add-base-path.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[4].use[2]!C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\client\add-base-path.js|app-client
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop\WD\NEXTjs\test\test\node_modules\next\dist\build\.................
```

The page loads though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
Next.js didn’t like having the app inside the Desktop/desktop/… folder, so it was throwing errors. I just changed the folder name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove `./` and then run the command.

`npx create-next-app@latest`

After, when command ask for project name just write `.` and hit enter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this. However, I still get the same warnings while running the app using npm run dev. Do you have any other suggestions?”